Concurrent exception in ASP.NET Core Web API with single database in Postman
Using VS 2022, I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project.
I have created the API and used Identity API and created wrapper class for the UserManager API.
Using DependencyManager, AddScoped() DbContext which was derived from the IdentityDbContext.
AddScoped<ExpIdentityDbContext>()
.AddDbContext<ExpIdentityDbContext>(options =>
{
  options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ExpUsers"));
  options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTrackingWithIdentityResolution);
});

In fact, I have added same database to another DbContext for the other tables which are not part of the Identity tables. For checking Web API methods, I have activated Swagger also.
I have created 2 controllers to creating new user, list the user, change the password and reset the password. In the AuthController, I have placed the methods for changing password and reset it.
With this configuration, I can login and create and list users. But the changepassword and resetpassword are not working as expected. changepassword is throwing an exception

Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified

and resetpassword throws

Invalid token

In my API, I have created a method to generate token using the
userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync

and I used the generated token to reset the password. But both in vain..
I checked several articles and searched for solutions on Stack overflow and tried them. But none solved the issue.
Any help on this would be appreciated

Show us how you call ResetPasswordAsync

hi @Pieterjan
please find below the snippet
public async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser appUser, string token, string newPassword) {     if (appUser is null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPassword) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))         return IdentityResult.Failed();     return await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(appUser, Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(token), newPassword); }

public async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser appUser, string token, string newPassword) {     if (appUser is null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPassword) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))         return IdentityResult.Failed();     return await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(appUser, Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(token), newPassword); }

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553964/how-to-deal-with-concurrency-failure-on-identityuser-update
